# Access controls from a Usercontrol that is programmatically added more than once?

Tags: c#, user-controls, controls, tabs, tabcontrol

Well I've search a lot, and can't find help anywhere.

I have a form with tabs. When I click a button, a new tab is added, and a usercontrol is added to the new tab.

I cannot figure out how to access the controls on the second + tabs. I can access the user controls just fine from the first tab.. just not the others.

Here is the code I had so far.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title = "tabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    TabPage newPage = new TabPage(title);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newPage);

    UserControl1 newTabControl = new UserControl1();
    newPage.Controls.Add(newTabControl);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = userControl1.textBox1.Text;
}
```

So when I click button one, say 2 or 3 times, and how do I get the text from the textBox in the userControl from that tab?

...maybe I'm going about it all wrong?

Comment: Please don't add things like " C sharp" to your titles. We use tags for that purpose on [so]. Also, the language is named "C#", not "C sharp".

Comment: What is "userControl1"? It seems it has nothing to do with tabs you create dynamically.

Comment: userControl1 is just the name of the usercontrol. The control is just a label and textbox.

usercontrol1.textbox1.text is how I am accessing the text properties of the textbox in the user control that is added to the tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend the TabPage and have properties that contain the child objects, for example:

```
public class ExtendedTabPage : TabPage
{
    public UserControl1 UserControl { get; private set; }

    public ExtendedTabPage(UserControl1 userControl)
    {
        UserControl = userControl;
        this.Controls.Add(userControl);
    }
}
```

Then you can access it via .UserControl as long as you still have a reference to it.. like so:

```
ExtendedTabPage newTab = new ExtendedTabPage(new UserControl1());
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTab);

newTab.UserControl.textBox1.Text = "New Tab User Control TextBox";
```

You will also have to go into the UserControl designer file and change the textbox declaration from private to public.

Comment: Also, you can then cast tabpages back to an extendedtabpage later down the track, for example: (tabControl1.TabPages[3] as ExtendedTabPage).UserControl.textBox1.Text = "Changed";

Comment: Well I got caught up in the excitement of it working, that I missed the part where it does not have a name on the new tab.

Where do you enter the tab name, when working with ExtendedTabPage?

Comment: ~ Sorry, got it. I just added the line newTab.Text = "title"; and that took care of it. Thanks again chem.