# Working with more than 2 dynamically created datagridview

Tags: c#

I am working on a Windows Forms application.  I have two tab2 in my window form.  In each tab, I build a datagridview which I named it dgvRound.  I loaded two different set of datas to the two datagridview in these two tabs. When I switch from tab1 to tab2, I still see the datagridview data on the tab1.  How do I change it (currency?) to see the dgvRound in tab2 which I update the datagridview with new data?

```
// tabView is my main tab page control
//  Add a new tab for a new round
string title = "Round " + Convert.ToString(intRound);
TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
tabView.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

// set up datagridview box
DataGridView dgvRound = new DataGridView();
myTabPage.Controls.Add(dgvRound);
// set up the datagridview column and row headings
SetupTableView(dgvRound);

//load datagridview in a loop with different data from different dataset
string[] row1 = new string[] { "array of datas" };
dgvRound.Rows.Add(row1);
```

I called the above code to create the tab and dgv multiple times depending on some variables. The data in each datagrid in each tab are ok.  But when I try to pull the data from datagridview (dgvRound) from tab2, i see the data in tab1 not tab2.  For example:
dgvRound.Rows[0].Cells["Game 1"].Value.  How do I tell it look at tab2.dgvRound.Rows[0].Cells["Game 1"].Value?

Thanks for your help
Daniel

Thanks HotSoft, I finally found the code to search for the current datagridview in a dynamically created tab page.  I added this and it is working now.
    TabPage CurrentTabPage = tabView.SelectedTab;
    // Get all the controls here 
    Control.ControlCollection col = CurrentTabPage.Controls;
    // should have only one dgv 
    foreach (Control myControl in col)
    {
       if (myControl.ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView")
       {
           DataGridView tempdgv = (DataGridView)myControl;
           tempdgv.SelectAll();
           dgvRound = tempdgv;
       }
    }
Thanks again for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I cannot see you code dynamically creating the DataGridView on each Tab

Looks like you are showing the same DataGrid on both tabs with out reloading or re-binding the  different datasource for datagrid's on different tabs

**Update on OP's comment:**

You can get the DataGridView from the tabpage like this

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = tabPage1.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>() as DataGridView;
DataGridView dataGridView2 = tabPage2.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>() as DataGridView;
```

Comment: Here is how I create the tab and dgv

Comment: @DanielDang I cannot see any changes on your answer or any link anywhere

Comment: @DanielDang please show the code that pulls the data from datagridview (dgvRound) from tab1 & tab 2

Comment: This is how I pull the data from the dgv  myNewValue = dgvRound.Rows[0].Cells["Game 1"].Value in a loop starting from Rows[0] to Rows[n].

Comment: I should add that I have a dynamic button on each tab also.  I know which tab page I am on. but just couldn't figure out how to switch to different dgv since they all have the same dgv name.

Comment: Cool I think all you need to do is search the DataGriView in controls collection of the tabpage and once the datagridview is found then try to pull data

Comment: I am new to .net and C#.  How do i search the dgv controls collection of the tabpage?  Thanks again

Comment: @DanielDang please see i have updated answer showing how to get datagrid from tabpage

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.  I put the three line of codes in and still see the data from the datagridview in the first tab.  I can see in debug tabView.SelectedTab has the right tab page 2.  I tried without the second line but the CurrentdataGridView has a NULL value.    DataGridView CurrentdataGridView = tabView.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>() as DataGridView;
            CurrentdataGridView = dgvRound;
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(CurrentdataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["Game 1"].Value));

Comment: @DanielDang the SelectedTab might be reading from 1st tabpage pls try the way i am showing in answer

Comment: My tab page is also created dynamically.  I just have one tab page control name for all the tab pages.  I tried this - TabPage  myTabPage = tabView.SelectedTab;
DataGridView myCurrentDataGridView = myTabPage.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>() as DataGridView;  but still not getting the right dgv.

Comment: Hi HatSoft, I search around and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003370/access-controls-from-a-usercontrol-that-is-programmatically-added-more-than-once Can I use this same concept for datagridview?  If yes, what is the code like for datagridview?  Thanks Danie

Comment: Hi HatSoft,  It is working now. I updated my question with the solution.  Thanks again

Comment: Make sure you select his answer as the answer to your question as well @DanielDang

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont create two different DataGridViews for each tabPage?
Or if you want to use only 1 dgv on both tabs, then clear it (set datasource to null) and set new datasource for next tab.

Comment: I don't know ahead of time how many tabs will be created.  Each tab has a datagrid with different set of data.  The structure of the datagrid is the same in each tab.  Now I have it as dgvRound.